# Get UICollectionView cell ID inside of a JSON array and make it global

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uicollectionview

I want to set the value I get inside my JSON array for the ID of my UICollectionView cell. I need to display some data and it should be accessible from the cell.
I have defined an `Int` variable on top of the class:

```
import UIKit
import Auk
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SystemConfiguration

var productID = Int()

class SlideView: BaseViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    //My class
}
```

And tried to set a value inside a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let productsIDArray = topProductArrayResult.flatMap { $0["id"] as? Int }
    productID = productsIDArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Tried to recall it in an other view which is led to by pressing the cell:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(productID)
}
```

Prints `0` in console

This is what's inside of `productsIDArray`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, there was a `UIButton` inside the cell that did block the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` action

Also for the global variable did this on top of the class:

```
struct Global {
   static var productID = Int()
   static var catID = Int()
   static var productCatID = Int()
}
```

Modified like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == self.allCollectionsView {
        let catsIDArray = CataArrayResult.flatMap { $0["id"] as? Int }
        let catsID = catsIDArray[indexPath.row]
        Global.catID = catsID
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCat", sender: self)
    } else {
        let productsIDArray = topProductArrayResult.flatMap { $0["id"] as? Int }
        let productsID = productsIDArray[indexPath.row]
        Global.productID = productsID
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "product", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And called like:

```
Global.productID
```